# Javascript OOP literal access variable inside method

Tags: javascript, oop

i have a problem accessing variable inside method in OOP.

this is my code :

```
var slideshow = {

    elSet   : $(".slideshow"),
    next    : function() {

    },
    swipe   : function() {
                var clear = this.autorun().loop;

                onSwipe(function() {

                    clearInterval(clear); // not working
                });
    },
    autorun    : function() {

                var self = this;
                var loop = setInterval(function() {

                        self.next();

                    }, 5000);

    },
    initial : function() {

                this.swipe();
                this.autorun();
    }

}

slideshow.initial();
```

i want to clearInterval from **variable loop**,

on browser console return error TypeError: this.loop(...) is undefined

what's wrong with my code?

Comment: `this.loop().loop`? loop huh? `onSwipe`? Where's that one from?

Comment: sorry, i just edited the code, onSwipe is function for handling touch event.

Comment: `autorun` doesn't return anything, so `this.autorun().loop` makes no sense.

Comment: @ChingChing never update the question based on comments/answer. If you feel it has added value to question, add it at the bottom of the question under header **Edit**

Comment: @Rajesh, thanks for ur advise. i will take that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign the interval id returned by setInterval to a variable you can access, or like Barmar's answer return it.

```
    var slideshow = {

      elSet: $(".slideshow"),

      next: function() {

      },

      swipe: function() {
        var self = this;

        onSwipe(function() {
          //use the interval id to cancel
          clearInterval(self.intervalRef);
        });
      },

      // variable to store the interval id
      intervalRef: null,

      autorun: function() {
        var self = this;

        //assign the interval id generated by setInterval to a variable you can access
        this.intervalRef = setInterval(function() {
          self.next();
        }, 5000);
      },

      initial: function() {
        this.swipe();
        this.autorun();
      }

    }

slideshow.initial();
```

Comment: i like this method also, storing null object first then add something on it. thanks Murat for answering my question. :)

Answer (score 1):

#### Issues:

1. `var clear = this.autorun().loop;` Here `this` will have scope swipe and not object.
2. `var loop = setInterval(function() {})` Here `loop` will have scope of `autorun` and will expire after function execution is over.

You can try something like this:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/74m1f9xL/)

```js
function SlideShow() {
  // self will hold current object reference for all functions
  var self = this;
  var interval = null;

  function next() {
    console.log('next');
  }

  function swipe() {
    onSwipe(function() {
      console.log("Clearint Interval")
      clearInterval(interval);
    });
  }

  // Private function
  function onSwipe(callback) {
    console.log("On Swipe");
    
    // Check if value is passed and its a function
    if (callback && typeof(callback) === 'function')
      callback();
  }

  function loop() {
    interval = setInterval(function() {
      next();
    }, 5000);
  }

  function init() {
    swipe();
    loop();
  }

  // Public properties
  return {
    elSet: $(".slideshow"),
    next: next,
    swipe: swipe,
    loop: loop,
    initial: init,
    interval: interval
  }
}

// Create a new instance of SlideShow
var slideshow = new SlideShow();
slideshow.initial();
```

Comment: Thanks Rajesh for answering my question, thanks also for ur information about scope in JS. this method also working, ;)

Comment: Glad I could help. This approach is called Function as class. Benefit of this approach is you can create multiple instances of same function and you can have private and public properties. If you look into this, do look for Prototype` once you have decent understanding of it. If you look before, it will make it more complex

Answer (score 0):

In the `swipe` function, you have:

```
var clear = this.autorun().loop;
```

This expects `this.autorun()` to return an object, and tries to access the `loop` property of that object, which should contain the ID of an interval function. But `autorun` doesn't return anything, let alone an object with a `loop` property.

Change `autorun` to:

```
autorun    : function() {

            var self = this;
            var loop = setInterval(function() {

                    self.next();

                }, 5000);
            return loop;
}
```

Then you can do:

```
var clear = this.autorun();
```

You also shouldn't call `this.autorun()` in the `initial` function. It's already called by `this.swipe()`. Running it again will cause two interval functions to run, and the ID of the second one isn't saved anywhere so that you can clear it.

Comment: i like ur method Barmar, so simple. thank you very much for answering :)